# How to make Visual Studio 2017 intellisense work with javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

Running on Visual Studio 2017 with the new Javascript Language Service enabled:

1) Create a ASP.NET Core Web Application

2) NPM Install a package which includes a d.ts definitions
   (e.g. npm install axios)

3) Try to consume the installed js in a plain js file 
   (not in a typescript file!)

4) You don't get any intellisense

[image]

If you import the library intelisense lights up:

[image]

So my question is:

What is the correct way to get intellisense without importing the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169330/vs-2017-javascript-intellisense-does-not-work.html

You can track the issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20993

Answer (score 0):

I think if you go to Tools -> Options then go down to the Text Editor branch, expand that and go to JavaScript branch, then expand that and go to Intellisense. There you can explicitly add a reference or you can check a box to download remote references. I haven't tried this but I think it should work, also I'm working off VS2015 so things may be different.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This does not work in VS 2017 anymore. VS 2017 uses JavaScript Language Service (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio)

Comment: Ah, apologies I can't be more help on this. I don't currently have access to VS2017 to check it out.